# Generate random numbers in C

Tags: c, random

I want to generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 20

```
int one = rand() % 20;
```

it gives me 1 steady value i.e 1...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code works fine.  http://www.ideone.com/52L8O

Comment: I think he's asking about the value of count...

Comment: You have your own function named `rand()` that you are calling instead of the C library version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a seed to the random number.

```
srand( time(NULL) );
int num1 = rand() % count;


int num2 = rand() % count;
```

---

Random number between 1 and 20

```
int num = rand() % 20 ;

if( num == 0 )
    num += 2;

else if( num == 1 )
    ++num ;
```

Comment: What if i want random number between 1 and 20?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html    `If rand() is called before any calls to srand() are made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand() is first called with a seed value of 1.`

Comment: @Mahesh - you shouldn't seed the random number generator before each call to rand.  Just once is fine (and preferable).

Comment: @SLaks: when you need a deterministic (ie, reproductible) sequence of pseudo random numbers, then you can use the same seed. But when your program does nothing else than printing a random number, you need a random seed.

Comment: @SLaks - OP says `it gives me 1 steady value i.e 1...`. So, there is need to seed the random number generator.

Comment: @Mahesh: If you don't seed the the C library random generator it gets seeded for you, which is what @SLaks said.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if `count` is one.
If `count` is non-one, your code [works perfectly](http://www.ideone.com/Qht6t).

However, as mentioned, you need to set a non-deterministic seed by calling `srand`.

Comment: Vinod K probably wants different random numbers every time he runs his program.  In that case, he should definitely seed it using srand.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random number in a specified range [min,max], do something like:

```
min + (int)((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (max - min + 1));
```

The method

```
min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
```

*may* be faster, but it may not give you a normal distribution of values depending on the RNG.

And as others have mentioned, if you want a different sequence for each run, execute `srand` *once* at the beginning of the program.